# Images being rotated after ImageJob but not wanted

Tags: c#, imageresizer

<strike>I'm having an issue with some images being rotated during the processing of ImageJob.</strike>

I'm having an issue with detecting the correct rotation of an image uploaded from some (modern) mobile devices.

The images are coming from an iPad mini and a Galaxy S5.  I'm taking portrait pictures but they get rotated after upload and resize.  If I take a landscape picture the processing works fine.

I have tried using the autorotate plugin but this does not seem to make a difference.

The code is basic and works on some images but not others as mentioned above.

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = base.Request.Files["photo"];
ImageResizer.ImageJob i = 
    new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file,
                              "~/OrigFiles/" + cvm.Id + ".<ext>",
                              new ImageResizer.Instructions("width=768;height=1024;format=jpg;mode=max;autorotate=true;"));
i.CreateParentDirectory = true;
i.Build();
```

I emailed the photo from the phone to my laptop and uploaded it and it worked fine which is odd.  Could this be a mobile browser upload issue?  The problem happens on both iOS Safari and Chrome on new devices.  What is odd is that on a older first gen Nexus 7 portrait images work.

**Further Notes**

Here is the diagnostics:

```
You are using plugins from the Creative Edition: DiskCache (Performance Edition), WatermarkPlugin (Creative Edition)

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.WatermarkPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.AutoRotate

Configuration:

<resizer>
  <plugins>
    <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
    <add name="DiskCache" />
    <add name="Watermark" />
    <add name="AutoRotate" />
  </plugins>
  <watermarks>
    <otherimages path="~/watermarks" right="20" bottom="20" width="20" height="20" />
    <group name="portraitBG">
      <image path="~/PORTRAIT.png" imageQuery="" top="0" left="0" />
      <text text="#{name}" vertical="false" align="center" top="818" fontSize="60" color="FFF" />
    </group>
    <group name="landscapeBG">
      <image path="~/LANDSCAPE.png" imageQuery="" top="0" left="0" />
      <text text="#{name}" vertical="false" left="50" top="650" fontSize="60" color="FFF" />
    </group>
  </watermarks>
</resizer>
```

**Sample Image**

Here is a sample image:
[Sample Image](https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples/blob/master/Portrait_8.jpg)

https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples/blob/master/Portrait_8.jpg

When I download the sample image and upload from my laptop it works, saved as portrait.  When I download it and upload from my phone (Samsung S5 Running 4.4.2) it does not work and is saved landscape.

Comment: post some code for us to look at!!!

Comment: I added the code but it is very basic.

Comment: You are passing the `autorotate=true;` Is that cause this rotation ?

Comment: I added that hoping that it would solve the problem.  I get the same result regardless.

Comment: Yeah, I am having the same problem. Setting 'AutoRotate' to true or false will give the same result.

Comment: Based on what you're saying, your laptop and phone are uploading different bytes. What client-side upload tool are you using? Some preprocess images.